# How to convert Pandas dataframe to a specific format

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like below

```
    data = pd.DataFrame([
    {"name" : "c","email" : "edfr@test.com","ml_pred":"valid","hum_pred":"null","score":0.83},
    {"name" : "d","email" : "edsd@test.com","ml_pred":"invalid","hum_pred":"null","score":0.12}
])
```

How can this dataframe be converted to the following format

```
    [
        ({"email": {"$eq": "edfr@test.com"}},{"$set": {"ml_pred": "valid", "score": 0.83}}),
        ({"email": {"$eq": "edsd@test.com"}},{"$set": {"ml_pred": "invalid", "score": 0.12}})
   ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `DataFrame.apply` and construct a tuple for each row:

```
out = (data.apply(lambda x: ({"email": {"$eq": x["email"]}},
                             {"$set": {"ml_pred": x["ml_pred"], "score": x["score"]}}), 
                  axis=1).tolist())
```

Output:

```
[({'email': {'$eq': 'edfr@test.com'}}, {'$set': {'ml_pred': 'valid', 'score': 0.83}}),
 ({'email': {'$eq': 'edsd@test.com'}}, {'$set': {'ml_pred': 'invalid', 'score': 0.12}})]
```